# Bitcoin-ruby returns "nil" value for bitcoin-cli calls

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, ruby

I am new to test "bitcoin-ruby" to parse bitcoin blockchain data. But while testing it, I am having issues to make some bitcoin-cli commands to get this to work. The environment I'm using is :

*Linux version- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
*Bitcoin Core version- 0.14.2
*Rbenv version- 2.4.3
*Gem version -2.6.14 
*Ruby version-
*Bitcoin-ruby version
*ruby -2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247)
*bitcoin-ruby version- 0.0.15

Here are the codes I am using to parse the data :

```
require 'bitcoin'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
RPCUSER = "***"
RPCPASSWORD ="***"

HOST = "localhost"
PORT= 8332

def bitcoinRPC(method,param)
http = Net::HTTP.new(HOST,PORT)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/')
request.basic_auth(RPCUSER,RPCPASSWORD)
request.content_type = 'application/json'
request.body = {method: method, param: param, id: 'jsonrpc'}.to_json
JSON.parse(http.request(request).body)["result"]
end
```

### The following bitcoin-cli commands are working via bitcoinRPC :

bitcoinRPC("help",[])

bitcoinRPC("getnewaddress",[])

bitcoinRPC("getchaintips",[])

### But following returns "nil" vale :

bid = "0000000000000000004bd4aff1966f6df18b1dba6f6ef83a878e526ab31eee73"
bitcoinRPC("getblock",[bid])-> "nil"

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is only using RPC to Bitcoin Core and bitcoin-ruby is not used.

The problem is the body parameter name when sending the request.
Change `param` key to `params` as follow.

`request.body = {method: method, params: param, id: 'jsonrpc'}.to_json`